# xss_clean(set_value('field_name')) or set_value('field_name') is safe enough?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

As [CodeIgniter3's documentation says](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-13-check-for-usage-of-the-xss-clean-form-validation-rule) ,

> A largely unknown rule about XSS cleaning is that it should only be
>   applied to output, as opposed to input data.

Should I always use xss_clean() before outputting user's data? Or set_value does that for me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `set_value()` does apply XSS-sanitizing by default.

However, be careful when using it together with other form helper functions, because they do that as well, and you don't want double-escaping. [As explained in the manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value), you can turn escaping off by passing (boolean) FALSE as the third parameter for `set_value()`.